# Xlwings Add picture throws error "pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "The specified file wasn't found.")

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

I am using xlwings to add picture in excel file, which throws the error

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "The specified file wasn't found.", None, 0, -2146827284), None)

So far I have tried all of the below options.

```
ws.pictures.add(path to png file, name=xyz, update=True, 
                left=ws.range('B2').left, top=ws.range('B2').top)

ws.pictures.add(path to png file, sheet=sheetName)

rng = wb.sheets[sheetName].range("A1")
xw.Picture.add(path to png file, top=rng.top, left=rng.left)

ws.pictures.add(path to png file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of each of the lines you tried

This will work

```
ws.pictures.add(path to png file, name=xyz, update=True, 
                left=ws.range('B2').left, top=ws.range('B2').top)
```

This wont work, there is no 'sheet=' argument for [pictures.add](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/pictures.html)

```
ws.pictures.add(path to png file, sheet=sheetName)
```

This wont work, `xw.Picture` does not have an attribute `add`

```
xw.Picture.add(path to png file, top=rng.top, left=rng.left)
```

This line will work

```
ws.pictures.add(path to png file)
```

However your main issue is presumably `path to png file`. You don't specify how you are setting this but for simplicity;

These two will work:

```
path_to_png_file = "C:\\Temp\image.png"
path_to_png_file = r"C:\Temp\image.png"
```

but this will give you the 'The specified file wasn't found' error:

```
path_to_png_file = "C:/Temp/image.png"
```